# Post request to the firebase cloud functions gives error 500

Tags: javascript, firebase, post, google-cloud-functions

I have a POST request to the Cloud Functions on Firebase. When I'm trying to make a request, I get a CORS policy error. Ok, I set mode: 'no-cors' and get `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()`.

Here is the code

```
 let myHeaders = new Headers();
 myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
 myHeaders.append("Accept", "application/json");

 let raw = JSON.stringify({
    "description": "Test item",
    "email": "testemail@gmail.com"
 });

 let requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: myHeaders,
    body: raw,
    mode: 'no-cors',
    redirect: 'follow',
 };

 fetch("https://someURl.cloudfunctions.net/someRequest", requestOptions)
 .then(response => response.text())
 .then(result => console.log(result))
 .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

The code is copied from Postman

Any ideas?

Comment: mode "no-cors" guarantees you won't get to access the result - though, the 500 error means the server has an issue - is it your server?

Comment: @Bravo it means I don't need to turn off cors?

Comment: not sure what you mean by turn off cors ...

Comment: I want you to check 2 things : 1. Cloud Functions deployment can fail if the entry point to your code, that is, the exported function name, is not specified correctly either through Cloud Console(https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying/console) or [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying/filesystem#deploy_using_the).

Comment: 2. HTTP functions require authentication by default, so here are your options for working around this limitation:
Make your function public.
To make your function public, you can either deploy it with the --allow-unauthenticated flag, or use the Console to grant the Cloud Functions Invoker role to allUsers. Then handle CORS and authentication in the function code.  Or you can authenticate your cloud function invocations using tokens.

Comment: @jaba Were you able to solve the issue from my comments? If not, then please elaborate on the details.

Comment: @PriyashreeBhadra. Turned out that the issue was on server. Now it works. Anyway, thanks for help

Comment: @jaba Could you please post an answer mentioning the same, so that people visiting this question have an answer, how it was solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As confirmed by [jaba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15019445/jaba), the issue was on server side. Also, same has been documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/ErrorCode).